# JsonView annotation for all fields of a object

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I include all fields of Java object to the JSON response (view) with out specify `@JsonView` on every field of that Java object?

Edit: I need this to achieve with out the use of another external library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON formatting for a Java Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331325/json-formatting-for-a-java-server)

Comment: I asked with out using a external library like gson

Comment: Without library? Write your own regex methods.but it can take a long time :)

Comment: i mean without additional library. I like to achieve it using @JsonView or any other way by utilizing jackson jar

Answer (score 8):

This is a common problem with `@JsonView`. The annotation is applicable only on methods and properties, so you cannot just annotate the whole class and include all properties.

I'm going to assume you are using this with Spring. That behavior is due to the fact that Spring chooses to disable inclusion of all properties by default in the ObjectMapper. Because of that, only `@JsonView` annotated properties will be included, while other properties will not.

You can change this by setting `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` to `true`. Like this:

Plain Java:

```
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
```

Spring Boot (add this to application.properties):

```
spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true
```

This way by default all properties will be included during JSON seralization, and you can use `@JsonInclude` and other Jackson annotations to control inclusions and exclusions.

Comment: I have spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true but the properties are not included anyways. Also, spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true is by default

Comment: Worked for me with spring boot 2.3.3 version.

Comment: Checked for 2.5.x- works! All fields without view included for view marked controller response

Answer (score 3):

Since Jackson 2.9, the `@JsonView` annotation can now be applied to the class level to have the behavior you are asking for.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9

> Allow use of @JsonView on classes, to specify Default View to use on non-annotated properties.

```java
@JsonView(MyView.class);
public class AllInView {

    // this will be in MyView
    private String property1;

    // this will be in MyView
    private String property2;

    // this will be in DifferentView
    @JsonView(DifferentView.class)
    private String property3;

}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me for some reason and I have jackson 2.12