# Set @JsonView over all methods from Controller in Spring

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I can set a @JsonView over all methods from controller? Now I have on each methods, but I want to have on whole controller because is the same view for all methods from controller.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346439/jsonview-annotation-for-all-fields-of-a-object ? If so, then no (according to -not accepted- answer)

Comment: Is another problem. For example: I have 2 controllers. For controller A I want to set View A for all methods. Same for controller B.

Now, I have
`@JsonView(Views.Web.class)
 public String getString(@PathVariable("id") Long id)` but I don't want to add manually @JsonView for all methods from both controllers.