# Best way to handle child data(array) in REST API

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am developing web APIs. (using java, jersey) (data format json)

Following is the sample data format.

```
customerID
customerName
customerCity
products
    product1  quantity1
    product2  quantity2
    product3  quantity3
```

As you can see in above data, products is an array(product & quantity).

To provide this data (in json format) I have used POJO:

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
    private String customerID;
    private String customerName;
    private String customerCity;
    private ArrayList<Product> products;

    //getters & setters for above 4 variables

    public CustomerOrder() {}  //Constructor without parameter

    public CustomerOrder(....) {....}  //Constructor with above 4 parameter

    public class Product
    {
        private String product;
        private int quantity;

        //getters & setters for above 2 variables
    }
}
```

To use above POJO:

```
ArrayList<CustomerOrder> customerOrderList = new ArrayList<CustomerOrder>();

ArrayList<Product> customerOrderProductList = new ArrayList<Product>();
//statements to add data in customerOrderProductList

//add data in customerOrderList
customerOrderList.add(
    customerID,
    customerName, 
    customerCity,
    customerOrderProductList
);
```

My question is, Is it the best(standard) way to deal with above data format? Or is there any better approach?

Comment: May be it will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331325/json-formatting-for-a-java-server/32332780#32332780

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the standard way to deal with the data format. You could switch the list with an array of `Product` if you really wanted to, but that's really not necessary.

Besides that, most json to POJO libraries (gson etc) don't need getters and setters - you can just declare the variables public.